# extract unknown digits from string

Tags: php, css, string, extract

I have a string like `"padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px"`.
The digits are however unknown so the can be 0, 5, 10, 25, 100 or whatever...

What's the best way to extract each of those to a variable?

```
(i.e. 
$number1 = first number
$number2 = second number
$number3 = third number
$number4 = fourth number)
```

Comment: member from more then 1 year, 8 questions, accepted=none.  any reason

Comment: No, you want us to solve your problem and then give no thanks for it or help anyone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haljan,

This should work:

```
preg_match_all('/([\d]+)px/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

It matches all numbers that are followed by a "px" and writes them to $matches.

Comment: Surely /([\d]+)px/ should be in quotes

Comment: And to get your individual variables as you ask: `list($top,$right,$bottom,$left)=$matches[0];`

Answer (score -1):

If You want to extract unknown digit from a string them you may use this:
$new_string_without_digit = preg_replace("/[0-9]/", '', $your_string);